# According to the identity laws, if A ∪ ∅ = A, then how comes A - ∅ = A as well?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This identity law is in a textbook I'm using but this question is also in the textbook and the solution is true. How can they both be true?

[image: Identity Law]

[image: Question]

[image: Answer]

Comment: Do you think the second statement is not true? Or do you think the two statements contradict each other?

Comment: You could just as easily ask how can there exist a value $x$ such that $(2+x) = (2-x)$?

Comment: How could one be true without the other? $A-\varnothing=(A-\varnothing)\cup\varnothing=A$

Comment: @GregMartin How can A with ∅ equal A, but A without ∅ also equals A?

Comment: How can $5+0=5$ amd $5-0=5$ both be true? That must have bother you long before you studied the algebra of sets.

Answer (score 1):

Think of what the notation means, I have yet not earned enough reputation to just comment. So I will post this is an answer.

$A\cup\emptyset$ is the set $\{x\in U \mid x\in A \lor x\in\emptyset \}$ where $U$ us the universe of discourse. Since by definition the empty set has no elements $x\in \emptyset$ would be a contradiction and due to Universal Bound Laws, $P \lor (C\land\lnot C) = P$ where $(C\land\lnot C)$ is a contradiction. Thus the set in question $\{x\in U \mid x\in A \lor x\in\emptyset \}$ reduces to $\{x\in U \mid x\in A \}$

On the other hand the set $A-\emptyset$ is the set $\{x\in U\mid x\in A \land \lnot(x\in\emptyset)\}$ here the later is that $x$ is not an element of the empty set, which is always true for any element and is thus a tautology Universal Bound Laws. More explicitly $P \land T = P$ where $P$ is some statement and $T$ is a tautology, since its always true it reduces to just the statement $P$. Applying that to the set in question $\{x\in U\mid x\in A \land \lnot(x\in\emptyset)\} = \{x\in U| x\in A\}$

Thus we can see that $A\cap\emptyset = \{x\in U\mid x\in A\} = A-\emptyset$

I hope this clarifies this, usually looking at the definitions and logical laws helps shed light on those questions.

Comment: Since you seem fond of $\LaTeX$, you might like this: `\mid` which is treated as a *relation* gives nicer horizontal spacing inside your sets, *e.g.* $\{ x \in U \mid x \in A \}$.

Comment: Thank you very much Sammy for the suggestion, I only know \LaTeX. I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thank you! I needed to know that a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

The empty set doesn't have anything in it.

So if you add everything in the empty set (nothing) you'd end up with the same. If you subtract everything in the emptyset (nothing) you'd end up with the same.

Imagine you have a set: $\text{Everything you own}$ and we added to it $\text{All the leprechauns in Antarctica}$.  As there are no leprechauns in Antarctica we didn't add anything.  The result is $\text{Everything you own}$.

Now imagine wetook $\text{Everything you own}$ and subtracted $\text{all the leprechauns in Antarctica}$.  Well you don't own any leprechauns in Antarctica (no one does) so you are left with... $\text{Everything you own}$.

More formally:

$A \cup \emptyset =\{x$ so that $x \in A$ or $x \in \emptyset\}$. As there is nothing in $\emptyset$ then $x\in \emptyset$ is impossible.  So $A \cup \emptyset =\{x$ so that $x \in A$ or $x \in \emptyset\}= \{x\in A\} = A$.

And $A\setminus \emptyset = \{x\in A| x\not \in \emptyset\}$.  Now as absolutely no $x\in A$ are in $\emptyset$ then *every* $x \in A$ is *not* in $\emptyset$.  SO $A \setminus \emptyset = \{x \in A|x\not \in \emptyset\} = \{x\in A\} = A$.

Comment: Breaking news! Spotted leprechaun in Antartica!

Comment: "Breaking news! Spotted leprechaun in Antartica!"  Bah... I don't believe you.  Everyone knows that only Striped leprechauns are in Antarctica.  The spotted leprechauns all live in Mozambique.

Comment: There is a captive population of spotted leprechauns in Texas, though.

Answer (score 0):

- $A-\emptyset$  is , by definiton of the " difference" operation, the set of all $x$ such that

(1) $x$ belongs to $A$

and

(2) $x$ belongs to $\bar\emptyset$ ( for anyset $S$ , $\bar S$ is the complement of S).

- But $\bar\emptyset = U $ ( for any object whatsoever is a non-member of the emptyset).
- In virtue of another identity law : $A \cap U = A$.
- So $A-\emptyset = A \cap U = A$